# Equation of diagonal ellipse knowing 2 foci and eccentricity

Tags: conic-sections

I am trying to find the equation of a diagonal ellipse knowing the position of the two focus points and the eccentricity. Online I can only find the equation of the ellipse where the two foci are located on the same y axis value. Any idea on how to do this? 
Thank you.

Comment: Find the equation of the ellipse in a more convenient coordinate system, and then rotate/scale the coordinates to make the foci end up where you want them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ellipse with focal distance $2c$ and eccentricity $e$ has major axis $2a=2c/e$ and minor axis $2b=2c\sqrt{1/e^2-1}$.

Thus, if you have the focal distance you can write down an equation of an ellipse with the right size and shape:
$$ b^2x^2 + a^2y^2 = a^2b^2 $$

Now to turn the ellipse counterclockwise by angle $\theta$, apply a rotation of the coordinate system:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} \mapsto
\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta)x + \sin(\theta)y \\
-\sin(\theta)x + \cos(\theta)y \end{pmatrix} $$
Stick that into our equation for the ellipse and we get
$$ b^2(\cos(\theta)x+\sin(\theta)y)^2 + a^2(\cos(\theta)y-\sin(\theta)x)^2 = a^2b^2 $$
You can now calculate the sines and cosines and simplify to get the equation into the nice form
$$ Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2 = a^2b^2 $$

If your target ellipse is not centered at $(0,0)$, you can translate the equation by replacing $x\mapsto x-x_0$, $y\mapsto y-y_0$.

---

Of course you don't need to actually compute $\theta$ and trig functions if you have the coordinates of the foci, because then $\cos\theta$ is $\frac{(F_2-F_1)_x}{2c}$ and $\sin\theta=\frac{(F_2-F_1)_y}{2c}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to implement it in c++, but it really seems complicated. Is there any simpler way to find the intersection points between two ellipses?

Answer (score 1):

Let $c$ be the half of the distance between two focii. Then major axis $a=\frac{c}{e}$, where $e$ is eccentricity. Minor axis $b=\sqrt{a^2-c^2}$

Find equations of major and minor axis.

$$\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\space$$ and $$-2xx_1+x_1^2-2yy_1+y_1^2=-2xx_2+x_2^2-2yy_2+y_2^2$$

Read $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ as:-
$$\frac{(Distance\space from\space  minor\space axis)^2}{(Length\space of\space major\space axis)^2}+\frac{(Distance\space from\space  major\space axis)^2}{(Length\space of\space minor\space axis)^2}=1$$

and apply!

**NOTE** : This is a property of **any ellipse regardless of orientation and center**. It can be proved from the defining property of an ellipse, and is another defining property of the same.

**PROOF**:-
Let $P$ be apoint with distances $a-t$ and $a+t$ from focii, $x$ from minor axis, $y$ from major axis. Then:-
$$(a+t)^2 = (x+c)^2+y^2\space and \space (a-t)^2 = (x-c)^2+y^2\space(Applying\space Pythagoras'\space theorem)$$
Eliminate $t$ to get $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

**DEMO** : [here](https://ggbm.at/E4wvANaW)

Comment: Are you sure that this equation works for diagonal ellipses as well?

Comment: Yeah, this is a property of any ellipse.

Comment: but how should I change x^2 and y^2? Shouldn't I take into account the centre of the ellipse?

Comment: What do you mean? You just to need to find the equation of axes. The center will be accounted by itself due to their intersection.

Comment: Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Equation_of_a_shifted_ellipse it is written that this formula only works when the axes are still parallel to the x- and y-axes.

Comment: Wrong it never says *ONLY*

Comment: This is a more general result

Comment: It sounds like @Pino doesn't know how the equation of a line _also_ gives the perpendicular distance between an arbitrary point and that line -- which indeed it only does IF you scale the coefficients correctly, and this answer doesn't explain that. If the procedure here is actually completed, when the dust settles the actual calculations turn out to be the same as the ones I describe in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F_1, F_2$ be the two foci, $e$ be the eccentricity, and $P(x,y)$ be a general point.

Using the definition of an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse), we have $\dfrac ca=e$ where focal distance $c=\frac 12 F_1F_2$, and also

$$PF_1+PF_2=2a=\frac {F_1F_2}e$$

Expanding this should give the equation of the ellipse.

Comment: This gives an unwieldy equation with square roots on the left-hand side, though -- whereas we know that _every_ ellipse is the locus of solution to a quadratic equation in two variables.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Remember that the eccentricity is $e=\frac{c}{a}$, where $c$ is the distance of a focus from the center of the ellipse and $a$ is the major semiaxis of the ellipse.

So:

1) if you know the two foci $C_1$ and $C_2$, you can find the center $C$ of the ellipse (the midpoint of $C_1C_2$) and the value of $c$,

2) than, using te eccentricity, find $a$

3)  remember that, by definition, the equation of  an ellipse, for a point $X=(x,y)$ is $\overline {XC_1}+ \overline {XC_2}=2a$

Answer (score 1):

One benefit of coordinate geometry is that it can eliminate detours
that go via angles and trigonometric functions. This is an example.

Given an ellipse with eccentricity $\epsilon$ and
foci $F_1=(x_1,y_1)$, $F_2=(x_2,y_2)$,
then a straight line $T$ is tangent to the ellipse if and only if
the product of the oriented distances of the foci to $T$ equals
the square of the ellipse's minor semiaxis length $b$:
$$(TF_1)\,(TF_2) = b^2$$
This allows us to immediately write down the coefficient matrix for the
[dual ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve):
$$N = \operatorname{symm}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\y_1\\1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x_2\\y_2\\1\end{bmatrix}^\top
- b^2\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 x_2 - b^2 & h & x_0
\\  h & y_1 y_2 - b^2 & y_0
\\  x_0 & y_0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
where
$$\begin{align}
    b^2 &= \frac{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}{4}
        \,\frac{1-\epsilon^2}{\epsilon^2}
&   x_0 &= \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}
\\  h &= \frac{x_1y_2 + y_1x_2}{2}
&   y_0 &= \frac{y_1+y_2}{2}
\end{align}$$
The [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)
of $N$ gives the coefficient matrix of the ellipse's equation.