# Finding the equation of a hyperbola

Tags: analytic-geometry

> Find the equation of the hyperbola with center on $2y+x-1=0$, with an asymptote $y+2x-5=0$, and a focus $(1,0)$.

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Comment: What are your attempts?

Answer (score 0):

First, verify that the given focus lies on the line $x+2y-1=0$, which means that this line is the transverse axis of the hyperbola. Then reflect the given asymptote in this line to get an equation of other asymptote in the form $px+qy+r=0$. An equation of the hyperbola is then $(2x+y-5)(px+qy+r)=k$. Finally, choose $k$ so that the hyperbola has a focus at $(1,0)$.

There are various ways to do the latter. For instance, you could use the methods in the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44391/265466) to compute the foci of the above hyperbola and equate them to $(1,0)$ to get an equation for $k$. Or, you could use the fact that the circle through the foci centered at the hyperbola’s center, either line tangent at a vertex and either asymptote are concurrent to generate an equation for $k$.

Indeed, the latter property suggests another way to construct the required equation. First, compute the intersection of the axis and asymptote to get the center $C$ of the hyperbola. Next, compute an intersection $D$ of the circle centered at $C$ that passes through the given focus with the asymptote (either of the intersections will do). From there, drop a perpendicular to the axis to get a vertex $V$ of the hyperbola. This construction is illustrated below:

[image: Hyperbola construction]

The semimajor axis length $a$ is then $CV$, while the semiminor axis length is the distance from the focus to the asymptote. The conjugate axis will have an equation of the form $2x-y+d=0$, and an equation of the hyperbola is therefore $${(2x-y+d)^2 \over a^2} - {(x+2y-1)^2 \over b^2} = 2^2+1^2.$$ I leave finding the unknown parameters to you.

Comment: Reflect the focus also: $(x - 1)^2 + y^2 = (\sqrt{(x - 5)^2 + (y + 2)^2} \pm 2 a)^2$ and equate the eq to a multiple of $(2x+y-5)(-2x+11y+17)-k$.

`R=QQ[k,a,b]`
`S=R[x,y]`
`((2*x+y-5)*(-2*x+11*y+17)-k)*b-(a^4 - a^2*x^2 + 6*a^2*x - a^2*y^2 - 2*a^2*y - 15*a^2 + 4*x^2 - 4*x*y - 28*x + y^2 + 14*y + 49)`
`toString oo`
`(a^2-4*b-4)*x^2+(20*b+4)*x*y+(a^2+11*b-1)*y^2+(-6*a^2+44*b+28)*x+(2*a^2-38*b-14)*y-a^4+15*a^2-k*b-85*b-49`
`J=ideal(a^2-4*b-4,20*b+4,a^2+11*b-1,-6*a^2+44*b+28,2*a^2-38*b-14,-a^4+15*a^2-k*b-85*b-49)`
`gens gb J -- | 5b+1 5k+144 5a2-16 |`
$$(2x+y-5)(-2x+11y+17)+144/5=0$$